# Group UITableView sections by date

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a JSON file with Title, startDate, and endDate. I would like to group my sections in my UITableView by dates and to add the date of each group as the header. I am unsure of how to retrieve the data from my groupByDate function to populate the specific sections. Would I have to create a new array from my groupByDate function.

```
   var eventList: [Event] = []
   var eventGroup: [[Event]] = []  

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return eventGroup.count
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    return v
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 3.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableCell


        cell.titleLabel.textColor = .red
    }else{
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = .black
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Just return eventGroup[section].count in numberOfRows. In cellforrow you can use eventgroup[section][row] to access your values.

Comment: where is the [section] coming from?

Comment: IndexPath.section

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the idea first. Imagine you just have **one** section of all your events. What would you have as your model?

- A title
- An array of events

Right?

---

Okay if the above makes sense, you then would need multiple of that said models. Right again? Now break that into more specific terms. Like actual model type.

---

```
struct Event {
    let title: String
    let startDate: Date
    // maybe an endDate object too
}
struct Section {
    let title: String
    let events: [Event]
}
```

So now you will need to provide an array of `Section` object to the table view.

---

But before that you will need to `group` your sections by the `startDate` object. **Swift** has a pretty convenience initializer of `Dictionary` type that allows us to group an array by choosing a particular property's value from the object in the array. Pay attention to the function below:

```
func groupedSectionsByDate(from events: [Event]) -> [Section] {
    let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: events) { $0.startDate }
    // here you will need a date formatter object that will be used to convert
    // the Date type to String type. It's left as an assignment for the reader
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter // init and configure it yourself
    let sections = grouped.map { Section(title: dateFormatter.string(from: $0.key), events: $0.value) }
    return sections 
}
```

The above function should get you the sections with titles as grouped by date.

---

Now how would you use it with the table view?

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    . . .
    let sections = [Section]()
    . . .
    . . .
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        . . .
        let event = sections[indexPath.section].events[indexPath.row]
        . . .
    }
    . . .
    . . .
}
```

Comment: @soRazor, this isn't the right question to ask for. You should already get it by now how you would use the method and where. Tell me, how did you provide the data to the table view previously?

Comment: I didn't ask you __where__. I asked you __how__.

Comment: Let me be straight to the point. Somewhere in your code you may have your JSON converted to `Event` array. This is the array you should be providing to the argument of the `groupedSectionsByDate(from:)` function. The function returns `Section` array which should be assigned to the instance property `sections`. And then you need to call `tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: To prevent yourself from getting lost in the codebase, I recommend you try this in a separate view controller class or even in a separate project if possible.

Answer (score 0):

#### update

The initial data of the hypothesis is like this

```
[
    {
        "title": "Bicycling with Friends",
        "start": "11-01-2018"
    },
    {
        "title": "Yoga",
        "start": "11-01-2018"
    },
    {
        "title": "Yoga",
        "start": "11-02-2018"
    }
]
```

If you want to group display, you need to assemble the array into dates like this, each group of titles can use `start`

```
[
    [
        {
            "title": "Bicycling with Friends",
            "start": "11-01-2018"
        },
        {
            "title": "Yoga",
            "start": "11-01-2018"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "title": "Yoga",
            "start": "11-02-2018"
        }
    ]
]
```

I think your data source can hold a two-dimensional array `eventGroup`, or a dated dictionary `[dateString : [event]]`. Only use `eventGroup` can be modified to be like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return eventGroup[section].count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return eventGroup.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let events = eventGroup[section]
    let event = events.first

    return event?.title //Replace with the header title you want
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableCell

    let events = eventGroup[indexPath.section]
    let dateRow = events[indexPath.row].start
    let dateRowEnd = events[indexPath.row].end

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    let myString = formatter.string(from: dateRow)
    let yourDate = formatter.date(from: myString)
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy h:mm a"
    let myStringafd = formatter.string(from: yourDate!)

    cell.titleLabel.text = eventList[indexPath.row].title
    cell.dateStartLabel.text = "Start date: \(myStringafd)"
    if events[indexPath.row].conflict == true {

        cell.titleLabel.textColor = .red
    }else{
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = .black
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Then you need to check the `eventGroup `, whether it is the structure you want, adjust to the `eventGroup` you want. This way is completely displayed according to `eventGroup`, each element is a group.

Comment: For example, `var eventGroup = [[Event], [Event], [Event]]` is equivalent to, there are three groups, each array element is an array, the contents of each cell are placed in the array. You want each group to be a different date, you need to re-filter the data, store it in `eventGroup`

Comment: Yes, you can do this

Comment: No, it just helps to understand the format after grouping.